# Count joined rows with createQueryBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a query that joins several tables,

```
$qb = $dbm->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('job', 'tasks')
   ->from('MyJobBundle:Job', 'job')
   ->innerJoin('job.tasks', 'job_tasks');
```

This works as expected and I have an array of tasks for every job.  I want to just count the number of tasks but not return them.  Something like,

```
$qb = $dbm->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('job', 'count(job.tasks) as num_tasks')
   ->from('MyJobBundle:Job', 'job')
   ->innerJoin('job.tasks', 'job_tasks');
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$qb->select('count(job_tasks) as num_tasks')
   ->from('MyJobBundle:Job', 'job')
   ->innerJoin('job.tasks', 'job_tasks')
   ->groupBy('job')
   ->getQuery()
   ->getResult();
```

That should return the counts for each `job` value

Comment: I want the number of tasks per job to be in a column called num_tasks.  In SQL SELECT *, count(job.tasks) as num_tasks FROM job; would usually work.

Comment: Ignore the semicolon at the end of job.  the joins come after the from.

Comment: @shapeshifter updated my answer to add alias - i have no idea what your other comment means !

Comment: Sorry I was talking about my first comment.  This still returns a single value. I want an array of jobs with a column jum_tasks that counts the tasks per job.  I ended up using getScalarResult with select('job.id, count(job_tasks) as num_tasks') then getting all the jobs and looping through and adding the column manually.  the db should be able to do this for me.

Comment: @shapeshifter then you need to use `group by` and group if by job - see my updated answer